# Big O notation of sorting methods into graphs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I am having allot of trouble understanding big O notation and computational complexity etc. I think all the complex maths I found on the internet is just dazzling me.

I am trying to plot a graph to represent the efficiency of both the insertion sort and shell sort.

I think I understand that the worst case of a shell sort is n^2 and the best case is nlogn. Is this for all shell sorts? How do I represent this in a graph with the relevant axis of time and ?

Any help would be much appreciated, I am very lost.

Here is my code for my shell sort if relevant.

```
int const size = 5;
int i, j, increment, temp;
int array[size]={4,5,2,3,6}, i1=0;
//split the array into segments between the elements unil we reach beginning of array    
for(increment = size/2;increment > 0; increment /= 2)
{
    //increment through elements in array for comparison starting point
    for(i = increment; i<size; i++)
    {
        //set temp to last element in array segment
        temp = array[i];
        //decrement index by size of gap
        for(j = i; j >= increment ;j-=increment)
        {
            //compare element with element gap length behind
            if(temp < array[j-increment])
            {
                //swap elements if less than gap element
                array[j] = array[j-increment];
            }
            else
            {
                //if not break from loop
                break;
            }
        }
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I represent this in a graph with the relevant axis of time and ?
>    - N, the size of the input, is your independent variable and is represented in the horizontal axis (x) 
>    - Plot N^2 (the worst case) in the vertical axis (y)
>    - Also plot NlogN (the best case) in the vertical axis (y)